how to mount a root file system device with qemu-system-aarch
I were emulating an embedded linux system of FlyOS.img which includes DOS/MBR boot sector and two partitions,before that I had extracted vmlinuz and initrd.img from the boot partition of the img,the qemu command was executed as below:
qemu-system-aarch64 \
-M virt \
-m 1024 \
-cpu cortex-a53 \
-kernel vmlinuz \
-initrd initrd.img \
-drive file=FlyOS.img,format=raw,if=none,id=drive0 \
-device virtio-blk-device,drive=drive0 \
-append 'root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 noresume rw' \
-nographic

It did boot the img,but it stuck for a few seconds while mounting root system,then threw   Alert:device does not exists.Dropping to a shell! and dropped to initramfs.I have tried /dev/vda2,/dev/sda2 etc,none of them works.May someone help me figure out the exact problem.
